# android mqtt data persistance when offline

Tags: java, android, mqtt

I am trying to create android mqtt client in persistance data mode. Client connect ok and sends the data when there is an active network conenction. But if the network goes down i dont think the messages generated during the offline period are sent to the server.  i have tried with QOS 1 and QOS 2.

Should i catch the message not sent and store them in SQLite and try again when the network is up again?

MqttConnection.java

```
  public class MqttConnection implements MqttCallback {

      private final static String TAG = MqttConnection.class.getName();
      private static MqttConnection instance;
      private MqttAndroidClient client;
      private Context context;
      private String mDeviceId;
      private volatile boolean isConnecting = false;
      private MqttDefaultFilePersistence mDataStore = null; // Defaults to FileStore
      private MemoryPersistence mMemStore; // On Fail reverts to MemoryStore

      private MqttConnection(Context context) {
          this.context = context;
          this.client = null;
      }

      public static MqttConnection getInstance(Context context) {
          Log.d(TAG, ".getInstance() entered");
          if (instance == null) {
              instance = new MqttConnection(context);
          }
          return instance;
      }

      public void connect() {
          if (client != null) {
              if (isConnecting) {
                  Log.d(TAG, "Mqtt is connecting");
              }
              client = null;
          }
          mDeviceId = "Someid"
          setConnectingState(true);
          try {
              mDataStore = new MqttDefaultFilePersistence(context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
              mMemStore = new MemoryPersistence();
              // Construct the MqttClient instance
              if (mDataStore != null) {
                  client = new MqttAndroidClient(context,MQTT_CONNECTIONURI, mDeviceId, mDataStore);
              } else {
                  client = new MqttAndroidClient(context,MQTT_CONNECTIONURI, mDeviceId, mMemStore);
              }
              client.setCallback(this);
              MqttActionListener actionLister = new MqttActionListener(context, Constants.ActionStateStatus.CONNECTING);
              MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
              options.setCleanSession(false); 
              options.setKeepAliveInterval(1200);
              client.connect(options, context, actionLister);
          } catch (MqttException e) {
              Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught while attempting to connect to server", e.getCause());
          }
      }


      public void disconnect() {
          Log.d(TAG, "Disconnected");
      }

      public void subscribe() {
          Log.d(TAG, "subscribe");
      }

      public void unsubscribe() {
          Log.d(TAG, "unsubscribe");
      }

      public void publish(String message) {
  //        Log.d(TAG, ".publish() entered");
          String topic = mDeviceId;
          // check if client is connected
          if (isMqttConnected()) {
              // create a new MqttMessage from the message string
              MqttMessage mqttMsg = new MqttMessage(message.getBytes());
              // set retained flag
              mqttMsg.setRetained(true);
              // set quality of service
              mqttMsg.setQos(1);
              try {
                  // create ActionListener to handle message published results
                  MqttActionListener listener = new MqttActionListener(context, Constants.ActionStateStatus.PUBLISH);
  //                Log.d(TAG, ".publish() - Publishing " + message + " to: " + topic + ", with QoS: " + qos + " with retained flag set to " + retained);
                  client.publish(topic, mqttMsg, context, listener);
              } catch (MqttPersistenceException e) {
                  Log.e(TAG, "MqttPersistenceException caught while attempting to publish a message", e.getCause());
              } catch (MqttException e) {
                  Log.e(TAG, "MqttException caught while attempting to publish a message", e.getCause());
              }
          } else {
              connectionLost(null);
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {
          setConnectingState(false);
          Log.d(TAG, "connectionLost");
          if (isMqttConnected()) {
              Log.d(TAG, "Mqtt is connected");
          } else {
              Log.d(TAG, "Mqtt conenction is lost");
              reconnect();
          }
      }

      private void reconnect() {
          if (isConnecting) {
              Log.d(TAG, "Mqtt is reconnecting.. hang on");
              return;
          }
          if (isOnline()) {
              Log.d(TAG, "We are online so should restart connection");
              connect();
              return;
          } else {
**Log.d(TAG, "we are offline.. should i store the data in SQLite and resend them ???");**
              return;
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void messageArrived(String s, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
          Log.d(TAG, "messageArrived");
      }

      @Override
      public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {
          Log.d(TAG, "deliveryComplete");
      }

      private boolean isMqttConnected() {
  //        Log.d(TAG, ".isMqttConnected() entered");
          boolean connected = false;
          try {
              if ((client != null) && (client.isConnected())) {
                  connected = true;
              }
          } catch (Exception e) {
              // swallowing the exception as it means the client is not connected
          }
  //        Log.d(TAG, ".isMqttConnected() - returning " + connected);
          return connected;
      }

      synchronized void setConnectingState(boolean isConnecting) {
          this.isConnecting = isConnecting;
      }

      private boolean isOnline() {
          ConnectivityManager cm =
                  (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
          return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost according to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31826706/4615587 only the messages that are already on the fly only get persisted in QoS 1/2 modes. And that makes sense, since it has to work with DeliveryTokens to make sure the QoS is maintained.

So you will need to implement your own offline buffer. I've done this in one of my projects using a persistent job queue https://github.com/path/android-priority-jobqueue.

-Nowa

Comment: Paho Android Service 1.1.0 is now available and it supports offline buffering and automatic reconnect.